# Есть ли какой-то сайт, на котором можно написать предложение и получить назад то же самое предложение, но с добавленным ударением?

Tags: обучение

Есть ли какой-то сайт, на котором можно написать предложение и получить назад то же самое предложение, но с добавленным ударением?

Например, input:

> Я иду в магазин.

Output:

> Я иду́ в магази́н.

Comment: This question belongs more to language learners (or, say, software recommendations) but since it's already answered, let's just close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, есть:

- https://morpher.ru/accentizer

Если что, сайт и программу расстановки ударений разработал я.

Comment: Потрясающе! Но поправьте:http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=сверло&all=x

Comment: Спасибо! Несколько лет смотрел на эти сверла и даже нигде не засвербило :) Исправил (было: *свёрел*, стало *свёрл*). @V.V.

Comment: Потрясающе – это «Грамматический словарь» А. А. Зализняка. А мои заслуги гораздо более скромные. @V.V.

Comment: И малые чудеса вносят большую лепту.

Comment: " программу расстановки ударений разработал я." - круто, риспект :)