# Как объяснить, почему "светел", однако при этом "смугл"?

Tags: беглая-гласная

Мы знаем, что это краткие формы имён прилагательных мужского рода. В обоих случаях основа полной формы оканчивается на две согласные: светлый и смуглый. Ну а как, например, объяснить иностранцу, почему в первом случае пишем гласную Е (он светЕл — это не ударение, просто я выделил беглую гласную), а во втором случае (он смугл) её нет? Если это вообще можно разумно объяснить.

Comment: иностранцу следует запомнить эти два слова

Comment: объяснить то можно, но в такие дебри не всякий сусанин пойдет. Ответ вообщемто уже  все озвучил, но есть канал Микитко сын Алексеев на ютубе и там есть несколько видосов по окончаниям\спряжениям на примерах, как они эволюционировали - имеет смысл посмотреть - я посмотрел и общее понимание есть, но объяснить не смогу.

Comment: @MolbOrg есть теория которая индексирует типы спряжений, склонений и т.д. но это скорее для компьютерной обработки или формальной проверки нежели чем для запоминания человеком ("тип склонения 5в или 5а??"). Предикативные прилагательные - вещь странная вне зависимости от языка.

Comment: @Swift я говорил о склонениях старорусского(славянского? степень древности не помню) и по тем примерам у меня создалось впечатление о единообразности, отсутствие вариаций и исключений(скорее всего это не так, так как для этого нужен срез, достаточно большой текстов или чего то подобного, для того чтобы выловить исключения, если они есть) но на примерах это выглядело как эпоха победивших машин, знай себе лепи окончания согласно роду и падежу, 10 строчек кода Э-эффективность))  Это вот меня собственно и удивило. Исключения сейчас это смесь старого и нового, переходный процесс и остатки

Comment: @MolbOrg А так же в попытках упростить систему при обучении.. Нам упростили падежи до 6, а потом пытаются объяснить почему " в лесу" или "в соку"

Comment: @Swift про падежи там тоже есть видосик, познавательно, забыл уже что там конкретно было, но да еще один источник от сворачивания тензоров. Хотя вроде помнится посыл был не украли и не понерфили доп падежи, просто были такие себе формы, тоже наверно остатки на тот период. Мне про яти понравилось, их назначение как замена пробелов, превращая простыню символов в читабельный текст, требую возврата или скрипт автоматической бьютификации)) В общем и целом изменения просто так не происходят, и хотя это и порождает спец случаи, в целом вещь позитивная, хотя надо быть филологом, интересная наука.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Все дело в происхождении слова. В древнерусском «светлый» имело вид [свѣтьлъ](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%81/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9), а «смуглый» – [смаглъ / смѧглъ](https://classes.wiki/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-12359.htm). Исходя из современного состояния языка это объяснить сложно, проще запомнить, а лучше посмотреть в словарь.

Подобных слов (внешне похожих, но с разной беглостью гласных) множество. Например: ветер – катер. В одном Е беглая (ветра), в другом нет (катера).

Кое-какие закономерности есть. Например, в суффиксах -ец, -ень обычно есть беглая гласная: палец – пальца, конец – конца, парень – парня. Но после двух согласных гласные «не убегают»: пельмень – пельменя, беглец – беглеца.

Даже хорошо знакомые с языком иногда затрудняются, как правильно: дупл или дупел, сопл или сопел (от сопло). Меня недавно прилюдно [поймали](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/22968#comment-45129) на слове «свёрл», которое я неправильно написал как «свёрел». Век живи!

Comment: не факт что не правильно, сверел, может это слово из будущего))) язык эволюционирует и периодически возвращается к корням. сколько баталий было со звонит - а теперь все официально и так и так можно. Я написал в коменте под вопросом, но и тут тоже порекомендую - Микитко сын Алексеев на ютубе - про диалекты и спряжения склонения ударения и все эти видосы. Это не то что закономерности, это наследие старых форма склонений, как то так - те результат эволюции языка.

Comment: @MolbOrg Когда я говорю «правильно», я имею в виду «соответствует словарям, утвержденным Минобрнауки»: https://rg.ru/2009/08/21/russkiy-slovari-dok.html Никаких «свёрел» и «зво́нит» в этих словарях нет. Так что увы, «зво́нит» до сих пор официально не можно. А вы что имеете в виду под «правильно»?

Comment: Правильно - я таки и имел в виду - официально одобренное. Не знаю, толи я рано обрадовался, толи это победа и мне разрешили, или уже опять запретили(с мобилки чето не очень удобно, и так долго достаточно копал) в редакции 2003 года орфоэпического словаря Резниченко, в разговороной речи, коей я и пользуюсь, соблаговолили разрешить звОнишь(стр 340) что вообщем то и нужно, но закон про редакцию 2008 года, и тут уже все - не смогаю, ну вот прям счас. Ни в коей мере не подписываюсь на холивар, если что, завещаю это своим внукам. На грамотность тоже не претендую, ни в коей мере. Ваш ход - 2008ред-ия

Comment: Там и после этого была еще куча приказов, те может и не 2008 года редакция и может они еще включили какие словари - честно то ли места не знаю толи госву все еще придется обзавестись чем то чтобы рядовой гражданин таки имел доступ к правовым базам без задержек и юзабельно, вообщем дальше уже просто не смогаю этот клубок размотать к состоянию что у нас на сейчас, да и както ...  Но если вдруг вы сподвигнитесь на это, то я безусловно почитаю, слежу за этим с трепетом, как за чемпионатами мира по футболу, раз в декаду, другую

Comment: Действительно, в Резниченко, 2003 говорится, что «в разг. речи возм. зво́нишь»: http://slovana.ru/slovari/reznichenko/orfoepicheskij-slovar-reznichenko_0340.htm Интересно. Издание 2008 года в сети не нашел.

Comment: Посмотри канал который я рекомендовал, я вроде с видоса "Old Moscow Dialect and what is left of it"(не уверен то ли гугл переводит то ли так и называется, с этими ai счас и не разберешь) начал там залипал и смотреть видосы которые привлекали названиями, там можно распознать те которые про спряжения и историю языка - у человека вроде образование соответствующее и интересно рассказывает и копает глубоко. Я не считаю себя безграмотным, хотя с правописанием беда конечно и все прочее, но исторические экскурсы расширили мой горизонт и позволили по другому воспринимать некоторые вещи.

Comment: Я за стандартизацию языка, полностью приветствую, это если что, так же как и госты и rfc, iso и тд. Те чтобы был стандарт. Стандартизация на научной основе, с уважением к логике языка и тем фактом что он продолжает эволюционировать и развиваться. Язык один из наиглавнейших инструментов - он должен быть заточен, настроен и оттюнингован. Переносы ударений, изменения окончаний имеют какую то практическую пользу, иначе бы они не происходили. Интересно что старые формы склонений имели даже более логичную структуру.